# How to enable authentication for cargo webapp in jetty container? (docs does not work for me)

Tags: authentication, jetty, servlet, web-applications

It looks like I'm stuck with a simple and well documented issue, but nevertheless.
I'm trying to enable basic authentication in cargo web-app deployed to the Jetty server.

I'm following this document - http://cargo.codehaus.org/Jetty+Remote+Deployer, here's what I've already tried:

- Uncommented appropriate section cargos's `web.xml` file.
- Copied `demo-base/etc/test-realm.xml` to `etc/test-realm.xml`
- Added and edited `etc/realm.properties` file (which is referenced in `test-realm.xml`).
- Added `etc/test-realm.xml` string to `start.ini` file

Nevertheless, after restarting cargo web app does not requires authentication just as before changes.

Here's params with which I'm launching jetty service

```
shabunc@shabunc:/opt/jetty$ sudo service jetty check
Checking arguments to Jetty: 
START_INI      =  /opt/jetty/start.ini
JETTY_HOME     =  /opt/jetty
JETTY_BASE     =  /opt/jetty
JETTY_CONF     =  /opt/jetty/etc/jetty.conf
JETTY_PID      =  /var/run/jetty.pid
JETTY_START    =  /opt/jetty/start.jar
JETTY_LOGS     =  /opt/jetty/logs
CLASSPATH      =  
JAVA           =  /usr/bin/java
JAVA_OPTIONS   =  -Djetty.state=/opt/jetty/jetty.state -Djetty.logs=/opt/jetty/logs -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty -Djetty.base=/opt/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp
JETTY_ARGS     =  jetty.port=8085 jetty-logging.xml jetty-started.xml
RUN_CMD        =  /usr/bin/java -Djetty.state=/opt/jetty/jetty.state -Djetty.logs=/opt/jetty/logs -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty -Djetty.base=/opt/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar jetty.port=8085 jetty-logging.xml jetty-started.xml
```

So, the question is: What I'm doing wrong and how I actually can achieve what I'm looking to achieve? Also, how can I debug such things in order not to bother you with such questions again?